# ¿Como puedo hacer un Select y un Update en una misma consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo 2 tablas:

Usuarios [Id, TipoUsuario, Email, Password]

Clientes [Id, TipoUsuario, Email, Password, UltimaSesion]

he creado una consulta de inicio de sesión a través del Email y el password buscando en ambas tablas para saber si se trata de un Usuario de la empresa o un cliente:

```
SELECT Usuario.Id, Usuario.TipoUsuarioId, CONCAT(Usuario.Nombre, ' ', Usuario.Apellidos) AS UsuarioNombre, 
Usuario.TipoPerfilId, TipoUsuario.PaginaInicio 
FROM Usuario INNER JOIN TipoUsuario
ON Usuario.TipoUsuarioId = TipoUsuario.Id
WHERE Usuario.Email = @Email AND Usuario.Password = @Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
AND Usuario.Status = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Cliente.Id, Cliente.TipoUsuarioId, CONCAT(Cliente.Nombre, ' ', Cliente.Apellidos) AS UsuarioNombre, 
'0' AS TipoPerfilId, TipoUsuario.PaginaInicio 
FROM Cliente INNER JOIN TipoUsuario
ON Cliente.TipoUsuarioId = TipoUsuario.Id
WHERE Cliente.Email = @Email AND Cliente.Password = @Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
AND Cliente.Status >= 3
```

Ahora bien, lo que necesito es hacer un update a la tabla cliente para establecer en su campo "UltimaSesion" la fecha actual.

¿Es posible hacer esto dentro de mi consulta actual?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: A que te refieres con una sola consulta?? no, no puedes hacer select e insert en una sola consulta.. pero puedes usar un store procedure para ejecutar todo de una...

Comment: Gracias por tus observaciones, he cambiado mi pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como lo estas intentando hacer no es posible en la misma consulta hacer un update de la tabla, entonces se me ocurre que puedes abrir la consulta en dos partes colocando los resultados en una tabla temporal y al final hacer un llamado a dicha tabla, asi en la parte de consulta del cliente puedes actualizar el campo que necesitas actualizar. la posible solucion sería algo asi :

```
Set Nocount on

SELECT Cliente.Id, Cliente.TipoUsuarioId, CONCAT(Cliente.Nombre, ' ', Cliente.Apellidos) AS UsuarioNombre, 
        '0' AS TipoPerfilId, TipoUsuario.PaginaInicio 
Into #tmpLogin
    FROM Cliente 
        INNER JOIN TipoUsuario ON Cliente.TipoUsuarioId = TipoUsuario.Id
    WHERE Cliente.Email = @Email AND Cliente.Password = @Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Cliente.Status >= 3
if @@rowcount>=1
begin
    Update Cliente set UltimaSesion=1 
        WHERE Cliente.Email = @Email AND Cliente.Password = @Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Cliente.Status >= 3
end
else
begin
    SELECT Usuario.Id, Usuario.TipoUsuarioId, CONCAT(Usuario.Nombre, ' ', Usuario.Apellidos) AS UsuarioNombre, 
            Usuario.TipoPerfilId, TipoUsuario.PaginaInicio 
    Into #tmpLogin
    FROM Usuario 
        INNER JOIN TipoUsuario ON Usuario.TipoUsuarioId = TipoUsuario.Id
    WHERE Usuario.Email = @Email AND Usuario.Password = @Password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Usuario.Status = 1
end

Select * from #tmpLogin
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una función SQL ( en el motor de base de datos que estés usando ) que realice ambas acciones , realizar el select del usuario y si este se encuentra realizar el update. Además , retornar algún valor verdadero o falso , si el login fue exitoso. 
Saludos.

Comment: bmustach, bienvenido a SOes. Me parece que tu respuesta es buena. Quizas sea bueno incluir un ejemplo de lo que estas sugiriendo y de seguro podras ayudar mucho mas al autor de la pregunta.